# Top view in RelativeLayout ignoring clicks

Tags: android, listview, focus, android-relativelayout

I have a `ListView` inside a `RelativeLayout` and a small LinearLayouot with an `EditText` that should hover above the List.  However when I click the `EditText` it registers a click on the `ListView` underneath.  It seems it's a focus problem.

Here is code:

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llSearchPlaces"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="#dedede"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etSearchPlaces"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:hint="Search for Places"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <ListView
                android:id="@id/android:list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/nav_selector" >
            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

It want focus to be on the id `llSearchPlaces`.  But the two focus attributes I set do not work.

Comment: I see something weird... `Relative, Linear`, ... some Linears..., `/Relative, /Linear`?! - Shouldn't it be ....., `/Linear, /Relative`?? AND - Apart of that (which I guess is a **TYPO**), there's an **useless outer container**, which is bad for performances.

Comment: The typo has been fixed.

Comment: There's still one: weight=1 in RelativeLayout. Moreover, I don't see any use for having a LinearLayout around a TextView...

Comment: @DerGolem  Well `weight=1` is actually not a typo;  this `RelativeLayout` is one of a few views in the master `LinearLayout` (orientation vertical)

Comment: OK, I just didn't figure it out. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reordering the views in your XML layout. Ignoring the other views/viewgroups:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <ListView .../>
    <EditText .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The reason is ViewGroups tend to draw their children in the order described and pass touch events down in the opposite order, so Views that are drawn on top have a chance to act on touches first. If you order them in the XML as I describe, EditText draws later (on top of) ListView and will receive touch events before ListView does.

Comment: Well I need my EditText wrapped in a layout.  Picture how Twitter or the old Goolge+ style had a box at the bottom that you can write updates in (or tweet).

Comment: Also, my `EditText` needs to be seen.  I can't draw it behind the `ListView` which I believe is what the above does?

Comment: Views which are drawn later are drawn on top of views that draw earlier. Putting it after the ListView in XML means ListView draws first and EditText draws after (on top). And you can wrap it in a layout, just make sure that layout appears ***after*** the ListView in your XML.

Comment: See my other answer, it's less confusing and easier to maintain.

Comment: I marked this as the answer;  the issue was the ordering.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

First: Create layout xml for listview say listview.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/nav_selector"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp" >
     </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Second: Create layout xml for edit text say edittext.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etSearchPlaces"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:hint="Search for Places"
                android:inputType="textCapWords" />

       <requestFocus />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Third: Merge these two layouts in layout say mainlayout.xml

```
 <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/listview"/>

    <include 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/edittext"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: Replace ids and other attributes with your ones....

Answer (score 0):

On second look, I don't see why you need a `RelativeLayout` at all. The effect you are achieving is a fixed `EditText` below your `ListView`. In actuality, the `ListView` and the `EditText` overlap, and you are working around this by giving the `ListView` padding on the bottom equal to the height of the `EditText` container.

A better choice would be to use a vertical `LinearLayout` to contain the `ListView` and the `EditText` container beneath it. Here the `ListView` will take up all the space available that is not used by the `EditText` container.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ... />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSearchPlaces"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="..."
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        ... >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well, I am going to add a `TranslateAnimation` and when the user scrolls down, the `EditText` layout hides .. so I need the `ListView` to be shown underneath it.  I have actually removed the padding affect above.